# When did Putin state for the first time that there are no rules in international affairs?

Tags: russian-federation, international-relations, vladimir-putin

In a press conference mid-Dec (2023) Putin is [quoted](https://www.reuters.com/world/europe/highlights-vladimir-putins-annual-press-conference-2023-12-14/) as saying:

> "As for the 'rules-based order', there are in fact no such rules. They change every day in line with politics and the short-term interests of those who talk about (such an order)."

I'm curious: when did he become so *openly* cynical about the topic? I.e. what's his first public statement that closely resembles that (quote)?

Comment: Why openly cynical? Why not critically logical?

Comment: I find his comment very to the point. A few days ago I was discussing sects and religions, and a colleague of mine had a great comment: "religions are sects that made it". In the same vein, history is written by winners.

Comment: @WoJ
  Does it mean, that you and me are from different sects?

Comment: International laws are like the Pirate Code, they're more like guidelines.

Answer (score 5):

As early as February 2007 in the 3rd Munich Security Conference where he [said](https://www.files.ethz.ch/isn/94464/07_Feb.pdf), addressing mostly USA:

> In the name of one’s own interests everything is possible, it turns out, and **there are no limits**.

Although criticism of American "unipolarity" has long been a standard feature of Russian foreign policy, the hard-hitting tone was now quite different from that which prevailed in 2001 and 2002.

Comment: Somewhat aside, but since you mentioned the US, there's some interesting theorizing why they prefer that RBO term (see section #3 in particular) https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/leiden-journal-of-international-law/article/choice-before-us-international-law-or-a-rulesbased-international-order/7BEDE2312FDF9D6225E16988FD18BAF0 Even more interestingly, in 2019 a group of Russian scholars said that the RBO term is "anti-Russian" *par excellence* (section #4).

Comment: Funnily enough, someone coined the ["axis of disorder"](https://globaltaiwan.org/2023/12/the-axis-of-disorder-how-russia-iran-and-china-want-to-remake-the-world/) term. Not entirely inappropriately since as I found out, quasi official Chinse publications also slam the RBO term http://en.people.cn/n3/2023/0513/c90000-20018138.html Albeit that might not have made it to the lips of Xi Jinping yet.

Comment: Makes sense - it was around 2005-2008 that NATO made an open move to bring Georgia into NATO. This was perceived as a betrayal by Russia based on old talks and treaties with the west. Notingly France and Germany agreed with Russia. Putin countered it by recognizing South Ossetia and Abkhazia and breaking up Georgia. This statement reflects his thoughts during that period and highlights that he felt a confrontation was inevitable.

Answer (score -1):

Question in not definitely correct:

**1. *openly cynical*** - is a phrase or term relates to Machiavellianism :

> ..The Prince. The book would become infamous for its recommendations for absolute rulers to be ready to act in unscrupulous ways, such as resorting to fraud and treachery, elimination of political opponents, and the usage of fear as a means of controlling subjects. Wiki.

So, if Putin gave the critical review on the US politic - that is a logical fallacy to call his words "openly cynical", because his words is about *openly cynical* politic of the US. You can't call to opposite actions with same noun - that is fallacy.

What the US politic had mean Putin, for example 2003 year, the US intervention in Irak, because Calin Powell was shacking the bottle-with-powder in the UN as proof sense, that the Irak had biological weapon. What was in that bottle really? Could Powell bring the bottle with military poison in the US building on session? Of course not, but, the West media call that was really biological weapon in that powder. Is that was lie? Ofcourse that was a lie. Did the US or others find biological weapon in the Irak while the war? Nope, they didn't. They did lie, they did crime, and they realised their politic following the Machiavellianism rules. That was **openly cynical**.

Okey, little after, what had Hillary Clinton said, when Gaddafi was killed 20 october 2011? Just remember, she said: we came, we saw, he died.(changed a  latin "veni, vidi, vici") But what she said? She recognized with a lough, that the NATO coalition perform a collective killing the democracy leader of the foreign country. That is totally immoral, as a recognising fact. And this is **openly cynical**.

Okey,okey, what next. The US "Unwilling or Unable" doctrine. Who has a power - that one sets a *law*. This is an **openly and cynical Machiavellianism**. i make a point, only the US count a legal this doctrine.

So, im confused, when Fizz is calling Putin's criticism "openly cynical". Or i do not understand something, or something is wrong. Whatever? To do, recognise, or
declare something immoral is not *openly cynical*, and to criticism this cases is an *openly cynical* act?

**2. *rules-based (international) order*** - this term or wording in Russian, BRICS, China discourse, was appeared not later 2021 year. So Putin not the first, who said so, but his senses sounded at Munich Security Conference  in 2007 had layed down of the International Law discourse.

> Бен Скотт, бывший австралийский дипломат, утверждает, что само это понятие появилось в начале 1990-х годов и происходит из концепции либерального мирового порядка, характеризовавшего отношения между либеральными государствами. Представление о «миропорядке, основанном на правилах», возникло из предположения, что после распада мировой социалистической системы все страны примут вашингтонский консенсус, а либеральный мировой порядок распространится на весь мир. Ru wiki

i think, here is a source - [Ben Scotte](https://www.lowyinstitute.org/the-interpreter/rules-based-order-what-s-name)

Also this sources: [Rules-based (international) order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liberal_international_order) - wiki, and ru wiki - ["Международный порядок, основанный на правилах"](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA,_%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%85#:%7E:text=%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%2C%20%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%85,%D1%8E%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8%20%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F%20%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%85%20%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2). Here is also Lavrov(Russian minister of International Relations) [article](https://globalaffairs.ru/articles/o-prave-pravah-i-pravilah/) from 2021 same time as the Ben Scotte article.

i think, Putin said the wording at the first time in 24 june 2022:

> Некоторые страны в интересах своего доминирования в мире стремятся подменить глобальную архитектуру, опирающуюся на роль ООН, неким «порядком, основанным на правилах», кто эти правила придумал — непонятно, заявил президент России Владимир Путин, выступая на заседании в формате БРИКС+

auto translation:

> Some countries, in the interests of their dominance in the world, seek to replace the global architecture based on the role of the United Nations with a certain "rules—based order", it is unclear who invented these rules, Russian President Vladimir Putin said, speaking at a meeting in the BRICS format+.

Also, in Russian and not only discourse the *rules-based order* is opposed to the **International Law** - [11th Saint Peterburg International Legal Forum](https://rutube.ru/video/8e88784b05c6770190947d8da2400730/?r=wd).

And at last, China animation created a sarcastic cartoon about Uncle Sam and a kid dialogue about the rules - [**Uncle Sam's "Playground"**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q3BZMJ_V5vo)...

Why the US thought thay do well? Because there is a principle of an unfair behavior by player in the game theory: that, who able to plays unfair, while other have to play fair, have more chances to win. Is it an immoral rule set? Ofc. Is it openly cynical? - obviously!

So, Happy New Year, all the fair-unfair players! See you.